# DSolveValue gives a confusing result for a simple vector-valued equation

Tags: differential-equations

If we use `DSolveValue` on just about the simplest vector ODE I can think of, it gives the following result.

```
DSolveValue[v'[t] == {{0, -1}, {1, 0}}.v[t], v[t], t]
(* InverseFunction[Integrate[({{0, -1}, {1, 0}} . K[1])^(-1), {K[1], 1, #1}] & ][t + C[1]] *)
```

I haven't the foggiest idea what this even means. Helping it out with initial conditions just means it fails to find a solution at all:

```
DSolveValue[{v'[t] == {{0, -1}, {1, 0}}.v[t], v[0] == {1, 0}}, v[t], t]
(* DSolveValue::bvnul: For some branches of the general solution, the given boundary conditions lead to an empty solution. *)
```

Changing it into a pair of scalar ODEs works perfectly, however:

```
DSolveValue[
 v'[t] == {{0, -1}, {1, 0}}.v[t] /. v -> ({x[#], y[#]} &), 
 {x[t], y[t]}, t]
(* {C[1] Cos[t] - C[2] Sin[t], C[2] Cos[t] + C[1] Sin[t]} *)
```

This may be a bug, but I'm wondering if there's a way to work around this issue and either solve ODEs symbolically in vector form, or systematically reconstruct the vector solution from a system of scalars.

Comment: Agreed, Mathematica should be able to anticipate from the initial conditions that you want to solve a system. However, I don't see a question here. I think it would be a better idea to send this as a bug report to Wolfram Support...